# Formatting MDX programmatically using prettier

Tags: prettier, mdxjs

I would like to format MDX using prettier.

It's working on the playground, but I'm having trouble to get it running programmatically. In my code i get an unchanged result (no error, but not formatted)

Here is what i am doing:

```
import prettier from "prettier/esm/standalone.mjs";
const markdownParser = require("prettier/parser-markdown");

var formatted = prettier.format(content, {
  parser: "mdx",
  plugins: [markdownParser],
});
```

The following works on the [playground](https://prettier.io/playground/#N4Igxg9gdgLgprEAuEBiABACTgGxxdAdQgCccATAHSmoB5yBLAN3VfTBwEMBnbgXkoh43GIPQA+aq2x4IU9LQD0jJuJAAaEBAAOMBtG7JQnEiQgB3AAomEhlJxznOAT0OaARiU5gA1nBgAypwAtnAAMgxQcMgAZg7ccB5evv4B2t6RAObIMCQArokgcMHucOTkZWGcUJl5nJlwAGKkwZwwejXIIJx5MBAaIAAWMME4hIMMwulgcAG2k8yTzl1gvAORCSQwll6ZrbHxhQBW3AAeAVk4cACKeRDwBzgJmukkm13B5KcD2iSRMIQGOQYINkAAOAAMLzMCUIXm0XV+cE2TGimgAjnd4DsdHZutwALRRMplAYkOCYhjknb1fZIOJPQoJYIMHL5JmXG5Y6L0w6aGCcdyA4GgpAAJn5XgYOCyAGEIME6UVuABWAZ5BIAFUFdgZzxATAKAEkoBVYAEwH9dABBU0BGDOK6PBIAXxdQA), but NOT with my current code.

```
# Hello World

<div    class="test" >
  Hello
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i also had to add the parser for babel.

```
prettier/parser-babel
```